# iOS Chrome in China cannot add a pass to Apple wallet

Tags: google-chrome, wallet

Tried in multiple iPhones and multiple iOSs(version 10.0.0+), all have the same problem:

I can add a pass to Apple wallet in US, using Chrome & Safari.

I can add a pass to Apple wallet in China, using Safari.

I CANNOT add a pass to Apple wallet in China, using Chrome.

The error message is "Sorry, your Pass cannot be installed to Passbook at the time".

The error message in Chinese is "抱歉，目前无法将您的票证添加到 Passbook。"

Can I do anything to make it right, please?

Comment: Is it when you are physically in China? So language and locale is the same?

Comment: Yes, it happens when I am physically in China and I use China VPN in US. It happens whatever language and locale I use.

Comment: It seems like the certificate validation (which does include a server call) can't get through the Great Firewall. I would file a radar (bugreport.apple.com) and see what the response is. Best of luck.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect so to. Thank you so much! :)